# Find lowest date in each group

Tags: r, date, dplyr, min, tidyr

Hi there: I'm trying to find the lowest date in each group. The purpose is to find what date is common to each of several time series. Currently the data look like this.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
grouping_variable<-sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 500, replace=TRUE)
date<-sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2015/01/01'), by="day"), 500)
numeric_variable<-rnorm(500, 50, sd=2)
df<-data.frame(grouping_variable, date, numeric_variable)
```

And my working attempt is basically this.

```
df %>%
group_by(grouping_variable)%>%
min(date)
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `slice`

```
 df %>% 
    group_by(grouping_variable) %>% 
    slice(which.min(date))
```